# Detailed Per-Process Profiling

Tags: linux, process, load, profiling

I am looking for a way to profile a single process including time spent for CPU, I/O, memory usage over time and optionally system calls.

I already know `callgrind` offering some basic profiling features but only with debugging information and lacking most of the other mentioned information.

I know `strace -c` providing a summary about all system calls and their required CPU time.

I know several IO-related tools like `(io)top`, `iostat`, `vmstat` but all of them are lacking detailed statistics about a single process. There is also `/proc/$PID/io` providing some IO statistics about a single process, but I would have to read it at fixed intervals in order to gather IO information over time.

I know `pidstat` providing CPU load, IO statistics and memory utilization but no system calls, only at a high granularity and not over time.

One could of course combine several of the described tools to gather those information over time, but lacking a high granularity and thus missing important information. What I am looking for is a single tool providing all (or at least most) of the mentioned information, ideally over time. Does such a tool exist?

Comment: depending on the version of `ps` and the options available, some of that information is available there. But... yes, I would love for an all-inclusive performance console like found on Windows7. One possible thing to help ... there is a pretty darn comprehensive perf utility originally for AIX (IBM Unix) called NMON, which I believe has been ported for use on (some) linux(es). Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meanwhile I wrote my own program - [audria](https://github.com/scaidermern/audria) - capable of monitoring the resource usage of one or more processes, including current/average CPU usage, virtual memory usage, IO load and other information.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [remotetaskmonitor.com](http://www.remotetaskmonitor.com)? You can select individual process or thread, and then capture the cpu usage for that over a period of time. It will generate for you the cpu and memory usage plots.

Another option might be [cpuprofiler.com](http://www.cpuprofiler.com). But with this, your cpu data is stored in the cloud and you can login from a web browser to view the cpu reports.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. But Remote Task Monitor seems to run only on Windows (although claiming to be capable of monitoring Linux devices). And CPU Profiler only monitors a very limited set of application characteristics, plus the disadvantage of having to upload all the data to the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

[Oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/about/), packages available in most distro repos, provides optional per-process or system-wide event and process profiling using the hardware performance counters of the CPU.