# Detailed information on a single process in a greppable format

Tags: process, proc

Utilities such as `ps` and `top` are good for looking at many processes side-by-side. However, they are inconvenient for examining many fields of a single process and are not amenable to using `grep`. For example:

```
$ ps -o pid,ppid,tname,bsdstart,start_time,start,bsdtime,etime,etimes,c=LIFE%,%cpu,cputime,rss,%mem,stat,class,nice=NICE,thcount,args -p $(pgrep syncthing)
  PID  PPID TTY       START START  STARTED   TIME     ELAPSED ELAPSED LIFE% %CPU     TIME   RSS %MEM STAT CLS NICE THCNT COMMAND                                               
20149  1836 ?         19:24 19:24 19:24:58   0:24    01:54:12    6852     0  0.3 00:00:24 38428  0.2 Ssl  IDL    -    13 /usr/bin/syncthing -no-browser -no-restart -logflags=0
```

There is `/proc/$PID/status`:

```
$ cat /proc/$(pgrep syncthing)/status | head
Name:   syncthing
Umask:  0022
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   20149
Ngid:   0
Pid:    20149
PPid:   1836
TracerPid:      0
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
Gid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
```

but this lacks useful fields such as:

- CPU usage percentage
- CPU time
- Resident memory size / resident set size
- Memory percentage
- Out of Memory Score
- Elapsed time
- Nice priority
- I/O priority

The output I desire might look something like this:

```
Name: syncthing
Process ID: 20149
Parent process ID: 1836
Full command: /usr/bin/syncthing
User: exampleuser
UID: 1000
State: Sleeping (S)
CPU priority: 19 (low)
I/O scheduling class: 2 (best-effort)
I/O priority level: 7 (low)
Start date (ISO): 2020-06-15T21:21:53-04:00 
Start date (UTC): Tue Jun 16 01:21:53 UTC 2020
Process age: 01:54:12
Cumulative CPU time: 00:00:24
Cumulative user CPU time: 00:00:24
Cumulative system CPU time: 00:00:24
Out of memory score: 2
Out of memory adjustment factor: 0
Number of threads: 13
Number of child processes: 0
```

with more fields from e.g. `/proc/$PID/stat` and `/proc/$PID/statm`.

Does such a utility exist?

Note: this question differs from
[Detailed Per-Process Profiling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43936/detailed-per-process-profiling)
because I am not looking for performance profiling or monitoring over time,
but rather a snapshot of process information
for the specific fields mentioned above
in a particular format.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, such a utility *exists*.
I wrote one.
When version 1.41 of the nosh toolkit comes out, it will be available.

Fields are emitted in `vis`(3) encoded form, precisely so that they are machine-parseable by tools that break fields on whitespace.
One can, for example, feed the output into `awk` and do `awk`'s usual field matching, without (as is well-known to be the case with passing the vanilla `ps` programs' outputs through `grep`) accidentally matching something from another field.
Then one passes it through `unvis` to get the human-readable form.

Here is how I recently looked for my own processes, for example:

```
system-control ps -A -o "pid,args,stime,tree,tty,uid" | 
awk -F$'\t' '{ if ($6==1001) printf "%8u %4u %s %s [%s] %s\\n",$1,$6,$3,$4,$5,$2 }' |
unvis |
less -S
```

I'd modified a previous command in my history, adding in the `uid` field and the matching on field number 6.
This sort of thing breaks with the vanilla `ps` commands, because `args` does not get recognized as one field.
The `vis`(3) encoding here ensures that it does.

It fishes a whole bunch of stuff out of `stat` on Linux.
(The tool works on both Linux-based operating systems and FreeBSD.)
Columns are selectable via `-o` and `-O` if one uses the compatibility shim, as shown here.

Its output is actually a proper, machine-parseable, flat file table, single-TAB-separated.  Indeed, one can turn this into your chosen form with [Miller](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/reference.html) and suchlike:

```
% system-control ps -A -o "pid,args,stime,uid" |
awk '$4==1001 || NR==1' |
mlr --oxtab --ipprint --ifs '\t' --ops ': ' cat |
unvis |
head -n 10
PID: 4140
COMMAND: -zsh
STIME: 2020-06-16 08:39:05
UID: 1001

PID: 4554
COMMAND: sh /tmp/PCDM-session.sD4542
STIME: 2020-06-16 08:39:19
UID: 1001

%
```

Notice the spaces in two fields, which have remained encoded through processing until `unvis`.

Tools to get *reliably*-machine-processable process listings do indeed exist.
They are just not the (not really) standard `ps` command, or `top`.

## Further reading

- [`vis`](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?vis+3). *NetBSD Library Functions Manual*. 2017-04-22.
- [`unvis`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=unvis&sektion=1).  *FreeBSD   General Commands Manual*.  2010-11-27.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2020). [`ps`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/ps.xml). *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2020). [`list-process-table`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/list-process-table.xml). *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.

Answer (score 1):

The [`procinfo.py` script](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/2a44280b2e4a6bcb3ccc0b622acea3305807e175/scripts/procinfo.py)
does this, available in the source code of the python [`psutil` library](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
It is not, however, generally packaged with `psutil` itself.

Here is an example of its output:

```
$ procinfo.py $(pgrep syncthing)
pid         19383
name        syncthing
parent      1836 (syncthing)
exe         /usr/bin/syncthing
cwd         /home/nathaniel
cmdline     /usr/bin/syncthing -no-browser -no-restart -logflags=0
started     2020-06-18 18:04
cpu-tspent  0:28.66
cpu-times   user=19.73, system=8.93, children_user=0.0, children_system=0.0
cpu-affinity [0, 1, 2, 3]
cpu-num     1
memory      rss=42.3M, vms=927.6M, shared=14.6M, text=6.2M, lib=0B, data=129.5M, dirty=0B
memory %    0.27
user        nathaniel
uids        real=1000, effective=1000, saved=1000
uids        real=1000, effective=1000, saved=1000
terminal    
status      sleeping
nice        0
ionice      class=3, value=0
num-threads 13
num-fds     21
I/O         read_count=8.9K, write_count=1.6K, read_bytes=2.9M, write_bytes=896.0K, read_chars=2.1M, write_chars=126.2K
ctx-switches voluntary=32, involuntary=1
open-files  PATH
            /home/nathaniel/.config/syncthing/index-v0.14.0.db/LOCK
            /home/nathaniel/.config/syncthing/index-v0.14.0.db/LOG
            /home/nathaniel/.config/syncthing/index-v0.14.0.db/006717.log
            /home/nathaniel/.config/syncthing/index-v0.14.0.db/MANIFEST-006718
            [...]
connections PROTO LOCAL ADDR                REMOTE ADDR               STATUS
            TCP   192.168.1.153:57054       216.59.50.190:22067       ESTABLISHED
            UDP   :::35882                  *:*                       NONE
            TCP   192.168.1.153:45342       198.211.120.59:443        ESTABLISHED
            TCP   ::ffff:192.168.1.153:22000 ::ffff:192.168.1.175:41196 ESTABLISHED
            UDP   0.0.0.0:21027             *:*                       NONE
            UDP   :::21027                  *:*                       NONE
            UDP   0.0.0.0:33035             *:*                       NONE
            TCP   :::22000                  *:*                       LISTEN
            TCP   127.0.0.1:8384            *:*                       LISTEN
            UDP   :::22020                  *:*                       NONE
threads     TID           USER       SYSTEM
            19383         0.01          0.0
            19384         0.89         2.63
            19385          0.0          0.0
            19386          2.2          0.5
            [...]
            total=13
res-limits  RLIMIT                  SOFT            HARD
            virtualmem          infinity        infinity
            coredumpsize               0        infinity
            cputime             infinity        infinity
            datasize            infinity        infinity
            filesize            infinity        infinity
            locks               infinity        infinity
            memlock             16777216        16777216
            msgqueue              819200          819200
            nice                       0               0
            openfiles               4096            4096
            maxprocesses           63289           63289
            rss                 infinity        infinity
            realtimeprio               0               0
            rtimesched          infinity        infinity
            sigspending            63289           63289
            stack                8388608        infinity
environ     NAME                      VALUE
            ACK_PAGER                 less --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS --no-init --quit-if-one-screen
            APPORT_IGNORE_OBSOLETE_PACKAGES 1
            BROWSER                   /usr/bin/firefox
            DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS  unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
            [...]
mem-maps    RSS      PATH
            28.3M    [anon]
            12.9M    /usr/bin/syncthing
            1.6M     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
            164.0K   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
            [...]
```